# TypeScript - Get type interface in package node modules

Tags: typescript, axios

### Problem

For example, I would use a new `AxiosInstance` like:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:8888"
})

class Service {
    mainService = api;
}
```

Then I would like to add `changeService` method to `Service` class above:

```
class Service {
    mainService = api;
    changeService(api) {
        this._service = api;
    }
}
```

This would trigger type checking of `TypeScript` because of `changeService(api)`.

### Question

Because of `axios.create()` will return an `AxiosInstance`. Along with being new to `TypeScript`, I am thinking about trying to get the type of `AxiosInstance` interface of `axios` package.

How could I achieve this? Or are there better ways to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add it to what you are importing from the `axios` module.

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";
```

Then use it like so:

```
class Service {
    mainService = api;
    changeService(api: AxiosInstance) {
        this.mainService = api;
    }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221005#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN5wIIroCSAdmjAiQMYCmcAvnAGZQQhwBEyqaHA3AFgAUMKoQy8BGGBwAvIkJoAdFSg0EMGgApcAIwRoaAVQBKAGQBcnABYwYYCwHpHAGwhUEL6+hgWAHAF+HAwAlMKiLgZocADKNFAAbsC0OMJw6XAgCMAkcYnJdPJSwIJCGXBU1pQA5jR5SbRaxVYEPKTklLQhqWXlGTDWwMpZOfUFcojSpeX0wvRAA)